# '' is not a valid code for a 3 of 9 standard bar code

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I would like to generate a barcode using the .NET PDFSharp library. I'm creating a Barcode instance

```
BarCode barcode = new Code3of9Standard
{
    Text = content, // example: 'this text will be converted to a barcode'
    StartChar = '*',
    EndChar = '*',
    Size = (XSize)(new XPoint(120, 20)), // for testing purposes
};
```

but unfortunately the instance creation throws this exception

> '' is not a valid code for a 3 of 9 standard bar code.

I also tried to set a `Code` property but there is no. The constructor offers some overloading so I tried this

```
BarCode barcode = new Code3of9Standard(content, (XSize)(new XPoint(120, 20)));
```

but then I get the error

> 'this text will be converted to a barcode' is not a valid code for a 3 of 9 standard bar code.

I took examples from here

https://csharp.hotexamples.com/en/examples/PdfSharp.Drawing.BarCodes/Code3of9Standard/-/php-code3of9standard-class-examples.html

Does someone know how to setup a barcode instance correctly so that I can use it for the drawfunction

```
graphics.DrawBarCode(barcode, Brush, TopLeftOffset);
```

Comment: What is the value of the _content_ string? Barcode 39 has some limitation on allowable characters.

Comment: The value is a customizable string. Currently it's a generated string `Lot: Pnnnnnnnn; dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss; Scan Operator: [alias]; Page: n/m; Scan Profile: [name version] `

Comment: It looks like there are a fair few symbols you are trying to encode which are not valid for Code39. Is there any reason you need to use Code39?

Comment: I don't think so. I think I can use other ones too but it seems the class `Code3of9Standard` is the standard one?

Comment: @ phuzi would you recommend using other barcodes from PDFSharp?

Comment: please leave an explanation if you downvote..

Comment: Have you tried changing the string input to find out exactly what it has issues, with, such as re moving the ; [ / ] marks, or shortening the string...

Comment: I'm sure you're not limited to just the bar codes PDF Sharp knows about. You could generate a QR Code (or any other barcode) as an image and insert that in to the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Code 39 Barcode FAQ & Tutorial](https://www.barcodefaq.com/1d/code-39/)

> The symbology of the Code 39 character set consists of barcode symbols representing numbers 0-9, upper-case letters A-Z, the space character and the following symbols: – . $ / + %. Lower-case characters may also be easily encoded with the extended fonts provided in the IDAutomation Code-39 Font Package.

Without purchasing the [IDAutomation Code-39 Font Package](https://www.idautomation.com/barcode-fonts/code-39/) you'll have to stick to upper-case letters (A-Z), didits (0-9) and a few symbols (–.$/+%).

None of the samples you linked to use lower-case letters.